# DaVinci Resolve Fairlight advanced Noise Reduction

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve, audio-recording, noise, noise-reduction

thank you for helping me! My problem is that I'm working with a very noisy microphone, so just enabling noice reduction in the fairlight options doesn't do the trick. I'm switching from audacity, where I just **applied noise reduction two times**. Now, my question is if **the same is possible in Fairlight without completely destroying the audio quality**? I'm using DaVinci Resolve 17

Comment: If Resolve’s built-in  plug-ins don’t do the trick, you can always add your own.  They recently added support for VST3.  For $300, you can’t expect miracles from every built-in feature, especially since color correction, editing, and compositing are also included in that price.

Comment: Thank you very much!